# Using present perfect tense for an action that is still in progress?

Tags: vocabulary

My question is "Can we use present perfect tense for that an action which started in past and is still in progress"? if yes than how?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! As for your question, do you mean specifically only the simple present perfect, or only the present perfect progressive, or both?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a present perfect construction for an action which started in the past and is still in progress:

> I have lived in St. Louis for almost forty years.
>   I have answered questions on ELL since January, 2013.

This is called a *continuative* (or *universal*) *perfect*.

Note, however, that perfect constructions are inherently ambiguous. “I have lived in St. Louis”, for instance, may be understood in either the continuative sense or in an *existential* (or *experiential*) sense, which signifies that the prior action took place at least once:

> CONTINUATIVE: I have lived in St. Louis since 1976, and am living there still.
>   EXISTENTIAL: I have lived in St. Louis—I worked there in the 1990s—so I am familiar with the major streets.

There is, consequently, a tendency in Present-day English to ‘mark’ the continuative use with a present perfect progressive:

> I **have been living** in St. Louis since 1976.

But this is not required. Usually the context will make clear what sense you intend a perfect to bear.

There is a great deal more about the use of perfect constructions at [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially §§ [3.1 Grammatical meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32), [3.2 Pragmatic meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32) and [4. When and how should I use the perfect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13262/32).

Answer (score -1):

No, afaik **present perfect tense** is always used for when an action started in the past and ended in the past.

If an action started in the past and is still going in you should use **Future Perfect Tense** (will have/going to have + past participle) which is quite similar to what you were looking for.

*example:* "I am not going to have finished this answer by 4pm." ([source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureperfect.html))

Comment: There are two errors in this. 1) The perfect **is** used for actions which continue into the present - "I have been living here for forty years." 2) In your example, the verb *finish* does not signify an action which is going on in the present but a future event which will bring a present action (presumably "answering") to an end.

Comment: Oh gosh I'm so sorry, I only tried to help. I shouldn't answer then as native german. I regret! Won't happen again :(

Comment: Not a problem - we all make mistakes from time to time. This is in fact an important distinction between English and German: German *Perfekt* is what linguists call *perfective*, whereas English *Perfect* is not. This comes about, I think, because we have a regular *imperfective*, *was VERBing*; that leaves the simple past (preterite) *VERBed* free to take the *perfective* role, whereas your language uses the *Präteritum* mostly as an *imperfective* and needs the *Perfekt* to play the *perfective* role.

Comment: You are totally right, this might be the point. Thanks for correcting me and sorry again. How can I give you a vote for "useful comment"? You earn it ;)